# two interfaces on the same device on different subnets

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, switching

I've been told that it is bad practice to have two interfaces on the same device on the same subnet. i.e. two Ethernet ports on a switch should be on different subnets. Could somebody explain why this is the case? (preferably simply as possible as I'm new to networking)

Comment: can you make "to interfaces" -> "two interfaces"?

Answer (score 0):

Because routing in your OS normally sets one of Ethernet card as out gate to specified subnet and all traffic to this subnet will have only 1 output. Second route to same subnet will have bigger Metrik value and will use to send some data if first interface is down. Even if somebody will send request to second interface answer can have first Ip as sender. 
If you try to increase throughput to subnet you must use aggregation of Ethernet link. you`ll have 2 physically link and 1 IP.

Answer (score 0):

subnet is the logical division of the IP network based on the subnet-mask/netmask. So unless you plan to have two different separate networks, you need not to have two different subnets. This [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html) explains most of the possible cases to explain what it means by subnetworks on a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Whether two interfaces on the same subnet is good or bad depends entirely of what you're trying to accomplish.

If you need link redundancy or a simple way of load sharing (L2 or L3) it may the right way to go.

If you need network/uplink redundancy or a more complex way of load sharing (L3 only) you connect to two different networks (multi-homing). This is also the setup for a router connecting the two networks.